# How to prevent Bootsrap Collapse on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that triggers Bootstrap's Collapse on click.

Within that div I also have a button that triggers a Bootstrap Modal.

Problem is, when click the Modal trigger, both the modal is triggered and the collapse. I only want the Modal to trigger.

Is there someway to prevent Bootstrap Collapse on click?

Eg:

```
    $("[data-toggle='collapse'] [data-toggle='modal']").click(function() {
       $(this).parent().SomehowStopCollapse;
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your can use `event.stopPropagation()` it prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$("[data-toggle='collapse'] [data-toggle='modal']").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var thisModal = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(thisModal).modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Updated your code to trigger the modal as well.

Comment: I was wrongly convinced that it doesn't work for me, but I realised I stopped propagation of `change` event. Stopping it for `click` works well.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the trigger into an event use `event.preventDefault` or use `event.stopPropagation()` to not trigger event into parents.

It is something like what you need?

ejem.

```
$("[data-toggle='collapse'] [data-toggle='modal']").click(function() {
       event.stopPropagation() // or 
       event.preventDefault
       $(this).parent().SomehowStopCollapse;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the data-toggle='collapse' in your button, dont forget to put proper target also...